# Get Previous Page URL via JavaScript after window.open

Tags: javascript

If I have a script which calls `window.open`, loading a new page into the same window, then that new page's JavaScript needs to identify the Previous Page's URL - what is the best way to find it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use window.opener.location.href , it will give you the URL of the parent page from which you opened a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.opener` to obtain a reference to the window that opened the current window. Not sure if this is what you are after. When using `window.open` it will result in a new window, not sure what you mean by "open new window in the same screen".

Comment: we can open new screen in the same window like window.open("About.html", '_self'). And in the new screen i want the previous page url.

Comment: Can you pass a parameter to the new page?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Window.opener` you can get it, like

```
var win=​window.open('http://heera.it')​;
console.log(win.opener.location.href); // will output the url
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4dQY/1/)
​

Comment: Actually i want to open new screen in the same window itself by using window.open("About.html", '_self'). so after this when i use window.opener.location.href is not giving any value